# Parse PDB Symbol and Resolve Address

Tags: python, debugging, windbg, pdb, pydbg

Using a python based disassembler + debugger I've found below instructions(example). Now I want to parse Microsoft provided public symbols to find exact functions its calling.

I want to know what are the available options/ modules to do the same. Can we just simply get the info from a static PDB files or its required to load that in memory while debugging ?

```html
call ntdll!0x33dec
call ntdll!0x22280
call ntdll!0x2df40
call ntdll!0x33cdb
call ntdll!0x2df29
call ntdll!0x325a0
call ntdll!0x32a96
call ntdll!0x32a79
call ntdll!0x220a4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample that uses `capstone for dis-assembly` and `dbghelp apis` for symbol resolving of an immediate **E8** call

```
import sys  #for argv[]
import binascii #for hexlify repr() spits out ugly mix like
        #'\xe8y\xff\' instead of  '\xe8\x79\xff' :(
from ctypes import *
from capstone import *
class SYMBOL_INFO(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
    ( 'SizeOfStruct', c_ulong ),
    ( 'TypeIndex', c_ulong ),
    ( 'Reserved', c_ulonglong * 2 ),
    ( 'Index', c_ulong ),
    ( 'Size', c_ulong ),
    ( 'ModBase', c_ulonglong ),
    ( 'Flags', c_ulong ),
    ( 'Value', c_ulonglong ),
    ( 'Address', c_ulonglong ),
    ( 'Register', c_ulong ),
    ( 'Scope', c_ulong ),
    ( 'Tag' , c_ulong ),
    ( 'NameLen', c_ulong ),
    ( 'MaxNameLen', c_ulong ),
    ( 'Name', c_char * 2001 )
]   
modname = sys.argv[1]
offset  = long(sys.argv[2],16)
sympath = "xxx:\\yyyyy"  # substitute actual path
base    = windll.LoadLibrary(modname)._handle
symaddr = c_ulonglong(base + offset)
print "Module name = %s\nModule Base = %s\nSymFromAddr = %s" % \
    (modname,hex(base),hex(symaddr.value))
dbghelp = windll.dbghelp
k32 =     windll.kernel32
hproc = k32.GetCurrentProcess()
dbghelp.SymInitialize(hproc,sympath,1)
sinfo = SYMBOL_INFO()
sinfo.SizeOfStruct = sizeof(SYMBOL_INFO) - 2000
sinfo.MaxNameLen = 2000
Displacement = c_ulonglong()
dbghelp.SymFromAddr(hproc,symaddr,addressof(Displacement),addressof(sinfo))
print "Sym At Addr = %s + %s" % (sinfo.Name,str(hex(Displacement.value)))
opcodebuff     = create_string_buffer(16)
memmove(opcodebuff,symaddr.value,16)
for i in range(0,16,1):
    print binascii.hexlify(opcodebuff.raw[i]),
print
MyDisasm = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_32)
for i in MyDisasm.disasm(opcodebuff, symaddr,1):
    print "0x%x: %s %s  %s" %  ( i.address ,binascii.hexlify(i.bytes),
     i.mnemonic, i.op_str)
    if(i.mnemonic == 'call'):
        try:
            symaddr = c_ulonglong(long(i.op_str,16))
            dbghelp.SymFromAddr(hproc,symaddr,addressof(Displacement),addressof(sinfo))
            print "(%s+%s)" % (sinfo.Name,str(hex(Displacement.value))),
            print "(%s+0x%X)"% (modname ,long(i.op_str,16)-base)
        except:
            print "Indirect/register Calls Not Handled Yet"
            pass
```

usage as follows

**python dumpsym.py ntdll 1041**

```
first argument is a string that represents a module 

second argument is a string that represents an offset in the module

so if module is loaded at 0xxxxxxxxx offset 1041 will point to the address 
0xxxxxxxxx+0x1041
```

**output**

```
Module name = ntdll
Module Base = 0x7c900000
SymFromAddr = 0x7c901041L
Sym At Addr = RtlEnterCriticalSection + 0x41L
e8 79 a1 01 00 64 8b 0d 18 00 00 00 8b 54 24 04
0x7c901041: e879a10100 call  0x7c91b1bf
(RtlpWaitForCriticalSection+0x0L) (ntdll+0x1B1BF)
```

Comment: One question , "offset  = long(offs,16)" what does this offset means  and what it expects?

Comment: offs ? you mean sys.argv[2] ?? if yes it is the second argument to be passed to the script and it represents an offset into the module pointed by the first argument  viz c:\>python.exe xxx.py  yyyyyy 417   where xxx.py is the copypastedsaved script yyyyyyyy is the module name myuselessdll  which may be loaded at  0xDEADFACE  and 417 is offset into the module so DEADFACE + 0x417  BECOMES offset DEADFEE5

Answer (score 0):

You can get symbols from PDB file using [DbgHelp API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679291(v=vs.85).aspx). This is the same API WinDbg uses, and you can use it to debug live processes as well as simply extract symbols based on offset of the loaded module. In your case [SymFromAddr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323(v=vs.85).aspx) function would be easiest to use to get symbol from an address.

Answer (score 0):

One non-automated but quick way to do that would be :

1. Load ntdll.dll in the debugger as a dump file.
2. Load the symbols using the public symbol path - or local cache.
3. Use the `ln` command. Like: `ln ntdll!0x33dec`